# Is it possible to bypass certain exception in unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, ldap

Is it even possible to bypass certain exceptions in `mockito`? This sounds crazy. You want to catch expected exceptions in the unit testing I assume. However I decided to give a try asking this question. Here is my scenario hope I could improve my understanding on `mockito` and general `unit test` principals via this.

I have to build a simple unit test for a particular class `Foo` in an enterprise web application using `mockito` unit test framework.

This `Foo` class requires `ldap` and `database` connections however due to a reason, I can not use development environment specific `ldap` and `database` in the unit test.

I just need to test part accessing `ldap` so that I decided to use `unboundid in memory ldap` which allows to create light weight directory at run time and remove it from memory after testing is done.

My question is during the instantiation of `Foo` class via `@InjectedMocks` annotation, it triggers chain reaction of calling many other classes and their methods. It threw many exceptions which I expected.

I am trying to find a way to somehow ignore some specific exceptions such as loading/reading environment specific properties files or database access and etc.

For my goal, I don't need reading prop files nor database access.

I read upon `ExpectedException` junit provides which is subset of `mockito` if I am not mistaken however I don't think its aim aligns with my intention of bypassing some of the exceptions. I could be wrong on this.

All I want to accomplish is:

1. Instantiate `Foo` class
2. Call one of its methods that would read a list of group from `In memory ldap`
3. Verify returned data

Here is water downed version of test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    private static InMemoryDirectoryServer ldapServer;
    private static Integer ldapPort = xxxxx;

    @InjectedMocks
    Foo footester = Foo.getInstance();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
        try {
            // execute instantiate in memory ldap..
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // do print out
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testLdap() {
       // before it reaches here exceptions were thrown
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        // do tear down execution
    }
}
```

Comment: What has been done to **catch** the exceptions?

Comment: `Foo` class is injected via `@InjectedMocks` not instantiated in the test method that has `@Test` annotation.  Exceptions are thrown before it even hits the test method. I am about to update my question with example code.

Comment: \@InjectedMocks should be used with \@Mock or \@Spy annotation - this is not shown in your example.  Moreover, how do you expect to \@InjectMocks to work?  On the constructor, on a property, or on a field?  If you can ensure it to work on the constructor - are you still expecting the exceptions to happen?

Comment: @Dirk Hermann: I appreciate your input. Although I read and tried a given example from tutorial site, I still don't have a good understanding how + when to use \@injectMocks and I do not know how to answer your question at the moment. I have taken a course change a while back to go with junit instead. Hope this post does not ruin the quality of SO...

Answer (score -1):

You can catch an exception like this:

```
@Test(expected = YourExceptionHere.class)
public void testSomething()
{
    foo(FOO_VALUE);
}
```